# Why is this tensor symmetric and traceless? (Notation)

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

When we have a symmetric traceless part of a tensor $T_{ij}^{{S}}$ = $\frac{1}{2} (T_{ij}+T_{ij}) - \frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij} T_{kk}$, how do we recognise that this is symmetric and traceless? I don't get how I can expand this ($i,j=1,2,3$) and see for myself that this is traceless and symmetric. This is in SU(3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check for symmetry of the components, well, pick $T_{12}$ and then $T_{21}$.

$$ T_{12}^{S} = \frac{1}{2}(T_{12}+T_{21}) - \frac{1}{3}\delta_{12} (T_{11}+T_{22}+T_{33}). $$

Finish the calculation.

Then

$$ T_{21}^{S} = \frac{1}{2}(T_{21}+T_{12}) - \frac{1}{3}\delta_{21} (T_{11}+T_{22}+T_{33}). $$

Finish the calculation, then compare.

For the trace

$$ \mbox{Tr} \left(T_{ij}^S\right) = T_{11}^S + T_{22}^2 + T_{33}^S =...$$

Now make the replacements.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry this is so obvious to me now. Great answer mate. Thanks!